# Apigility and Doctrine, getObjectManager returns NULL

Tags: doctrine-orm, laminas-api-tools

I successfully integrated doctrine2 into my apigility project. I setup my controllers to extend DoctrineResource and when i try to get entity manager with $this->getObjectManager() it returns NULL.

If i call the entity manager trough Service manager it works, but if i want to use parent methods like fetch, create and etc of doctrineResources it crashes because DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator (and other services maybe) expexts entity manager as a first parameter but it recieves NULL

Why this method (getObjectManager()) in trait trait ProvidesObjectManager returns NULL. In other project it was working. Here i started from scratch and cant find the problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `$objectManager` is never injected in your custom (extended) `DoctrineResource` listener.

Normally the doctrine `ObjectManager` / `EntityManager` is injected in the listener through the `DoctrineResourceFactory`.
You can see that [here in line 113 of the factory](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-doctrine/blob/master/src/Server/Resource/DoctrineResourceFactory.php#L113).

You need to check if the factory is correctly building your resource listener. Maybe you have not registered the factory correctly or something like that. But without any code it is hard for me to say where the problem is exactly occurring.

Comment: I put it on git...
https://bitbucket.org/rump_shaker/test/src/800e79f5e9eef1cbb133bdd467b711e039660ed7?at=master

Comment: Yes, I see. I notice that your `TestResourceFactory` is practically empty. Like I wrote in my answer you need to inject your doctrine `$objectManager` there into your `TestResource` instance.

Comment: @Ivo Any success solving it?

Answer (score 0):

`DoctrineResourceFactory` will only inject the `ObjectManager` in  the Resource that he create.

In Your code Who create the `TestResource` is the `TestResourceFactory`, I see this in line 28 of this file https://bitbucket.org/rump_shaker/test/src/800e79f5e9eef1cbb133bdd467b711e039660ed7/module/Api/config/module.config.php?at=master.

One way for resolve your problem is inject the ObjectManager in your resource by write some code like this in your `TestResourceFactory`:

```
<?php
namespace Api\V1\Rest\Test;

class TestResourceFactory
{
    public function __invoke($sm)
    {
        $config        = $sm->get('Config');
        $objectManager = $sm->get($config['object_manager']);
        $resource      = new TestResource();
        $resource->setObjectManager($objectManager); 
        return $resource;
    }
}
```

Another way is see how configure zf-apigility-doctrine to instace your resource.

I write  my API with doctrine  only with the Doctrine ORM Module to Zend Framework 2.

The idea of zf-apigility-doctrine is integrate with another tool. See this youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5apFQF3VE3M&t=5m30s.